# Nested jquery - when one function triggers then it should trigger another function too

Tags: jquery

Following is my code all i want when .clickover function being called then it should also call the `$(".popover").css` function. Kindly let me know how can i make such nested query

```
 $(function() { 
          $('#notc').clickover({
          title: "Notifications"

          },          function() {
            //$("div.popover").css("margin-left","60px");
            alert("hi");
            }); 

      })
```

Comment: Is your alert being fired?

Comment: @AleksG its a custom function used for showing bootstrap popover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the Bootstrap docs, the first function I found which may be of use to you is onShown, such as:

```
$(function() { 
      $('#notc').clickover({
          title: "Notifications",
          onShown: function() {
              $("div.popover").css("margin-left","60px");
              alert("hi");
          }
       }); 

});
```

Comment: shouldn't the `onShow` be inside the parameters, next to `title`?

Comment: @AleksG yup i noticed that too :)